# Has anyone created a DNN 7 user with the services framework?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm trying to create a user with the DNN 7 services framework.  I've taken my working code from my custom registration module and modified to work within a DNN webapi function.

When I get to the UserController.CreateUser call in the code below I receive a

```
"\"There was an error generating the XML document.\""
```

exception.  My user makes it into the aspnet_Users table and the DNN users table but does not make it into the DNN userportals table.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
private void CreateUser()
    {
        //Update DisplayName to conform to Format
        UpdateDisplayName();

        User.Membership.Approved = PortalSettings.UserRegistration == (int)Globals.PortalRegistrationType.PublicRegistration;
        var user = User;

        CreateStatus = UserController.CreateUser(ref user);
```

Comment: Can you share the code that is creating the actual user?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the issue.  I was not setting the portal ID for my new users and DNN was excepting out when it was adding them to a portal.  All it took was User.PortalId = 0 before the CreateUser call.

Answer (score 0):

I have found by trial and error that the minimum needed to create a viable DNN user is:

```
UserInfo uiNewUser = new UserInfo();
uiNewUser.Username = "<myUsername>";
uiNewUser.Displayname = "<myDisplayname>";
uiNewUser.Email = "<myUserEmail>";
UserMembership newMembership = new UserMembership(uiNewUser);
newMembership.Password = "<myUserPassword>";
uiNewUser.Membership = newMembership;
uiNewUser.PortalID = <myPortalID>;
DotNetNuke.Security.Membership.UserCreateStatus uStatus;
uStatus = DotNetNuke.Security.Membership.MembershipProvider.Instance().CreateUser(ref uiNewUser);
RoleInfo newRole = RoleController.Instance.GetRoleByName(uiNewUser.PortalID, "Registered Users");
RoleController.Instance.AddUserRole(uiNewUser.PortalID, uiNewUser.UserID, newRole.RoleID, (RoleStatus)1, false, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MaxValue);
```

If any of these are missed out, parts of the user are created in the database, but the user may not be visible in the Admin list of users, or an Exception may be generated. Other details can be added later.